# constexpr constructor won't show coverage data

Tags: c++, unit-testing, code-coverage, gcov, lcov

Today I was rewriting my matrix class to be `constexpr`. I have(had) 100% unit test coverage on this class but I noticed after I converted almost all functions to constexpr a part of the constructor is marked in the lcov as no longer covered at all.

Here is the class with just the constructor.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t m, std::size_t n>
class Matrix
{
static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value,
                  "Matrix can only be declared with a type where "
                  "std::is_arithmetic is true.");

public:
    constexpr Matrix(
        std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<T>> matrix_data)
    {
        if (matrix_data.size() != m)
        {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid amount of rows.");
        }

        for (const auto& col : matrix_data)
        {
            if (col.size() != n)
            {
                throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid amount of columns.");
            }
        }


        std::size_t pos_i = 0;
        std::size_t pos_j = 0;

        for (auto i = matrix_data.begin(); i != matrix_data.end(); ++i)
        {
            for (auto j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); ++j)
            {
                this->data[pos_i][pos_j] = *j;
                ++pos_j;
            }
            ++pos_i;
            pos_j = 0;
        }
    }


private:
    std::array<std::array<T, n>, m> data{};

};


int main()
{
    Matrix<double, 2, 2> mat = {
        {1, 2},
        {3, 4}
    };

    return 0;
}
```

I am using gcc 7.2 with lcov 1.13

Comment: What was asked here?

Comment: @ÖöTiib Why the `constexpr` code doesn't yield any coverage data with `gcov` enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have(had) 100% unit test coverage on this class but I noticed after I converted almost all functions to `constexpr` a part of the constructor is marked in the lcov as no longer covered at all.

`lcov`'s indication of *non covered code* means that `gcov` didn't instrument it.

Anything marked `constexpr` is evaluated at ***compile time***, `gcov` coverage data is gathered at ***runtime***.

So that's one reason I'd suspect, why you don't get coverage data for any `constexpr` function.

---

As you have templated code, I'm not sure if I'm up to date, but I experienced that `gcov` doesn't instrument templates very well, and you might be left with zero coverage data for them.

Similar reasoning as with what I said above for `constexpr`, templates are evaluated/instantiated at compile time. It would be at least hard to instrument all actually used template instantiations in a reasonable way.

Comment: "is evaluated" -> "may be evaluated, unless it is used to define a value template parameter, in which case it is evaluated at compile-time".

Comment: @rubenvb Well, as far I experienced `gcov` doesn't work that well with instumenting template code at all. Maybe that's the primary reason.